# Decompile .swf file to get images in python

Tags: python, flash

I would like to decompile a .swf file and get all the images from it, in python.

Are there any libraries that do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SWFTools distribution has a command line program, SWFExtract, that can do this.  You could call that from python to do what you want:

http://www.swftools.org/

http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any libraries available for python, but maybe you can have an offline process to decompile swf using [sothink flash decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) Also I did not come across any decompiler so far that is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

There are no public swf decompiler libraries for Python.

Use a 3rd party program and the Python [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to execute it.